# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet

Tags: java, maven, heroku, web-applications

I'm trying to run a java application through tomcat on a server but I keep getting this error message. I've tried adding in the correct dependencies into my pom.xml file but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm trying to deploy this application using heroku.

This is the dependency in my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and here's the full error message:

```
    WARNING: A context path must either be an empty string or start with a '/' and do not end with a '/'. The path [/] does not meet these criteria and has been changed to []
configuring app with basedir: /Users/nicobeard/Documents/falling-knives-capstone/Backend/./src/main/webapp
Sep 12, 2020 3:17:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Sep 12, 2020 3:17:02 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Sep 12, 2020 3:17:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
Sep 12, 2020 3:17:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
Sep 12, 2020 3:17:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebXmlFragment
INFO: No global web.xml found
Sep 12, 2020 3:17:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet [jsp] as unavailable
Sep 12, 2020 3:17:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [jsp] in web application [] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1291)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:512)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:493)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1050)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4931)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5241)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Sep 12, 2020 3:17:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

Comment: Try to add
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasper</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.32</version>
</dependency>

Comment: I added it and still the same error